# html2canvas: img tag with data src not being rendered in IE

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, html2canvas

Using html2canvas with IE-11 is not capturing img tags that have data srcs, but it works in Chrome.

```
    html2canvas($target, {
      ...
      allowTaint: false,
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
         ...
      }
    });
```

Part of the img tag

```
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,...">
```

This works fine in Chrome but not in IE:
http://jsfiddle.net/difftech/f4dtd5f9/1/

If I change the allowTaint to true, it works in IE. Why? Chrome accepts it either way. I need the allowTaint to be false so other content gets rendered from my page.

Is there a way to allow some content to use allowTaint or another way to handle this?

Comment: How large is the data? I recall IE having issues with very large data URLs. Also, can you confirm that the image does work in IE when loaded as a normal image, rather than as a data URL?

Comment: @Simba it works in IE if I change allowTaint to true, so I don't think it'd be the URL size.  Otherwise I wouldn't expect it to work at all.  Or is that how the issue manifests itself?